# how to make image background become image slider on behind form login

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to display a image background in my Login Page like cimb niaga mobile in which you can have a dot indicator slide running behind form login.

[I want like this image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9Pip.jpg)

this my code:

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
        void main() => runApp(MyApp());
        enum AuthMode { LOGIN, SINGUP }

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
          @override

          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            return MaterialApp(
              debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
              home: LoginPage(),
            );
          }
        }

        class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
          @override
          _LoginPageState createState() => _LoginPageState();
        }

        class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
          // To adjust the layout according to the screen size
          // so that our layout remains responsive ,we need to
          // calculate the screen height
          double screenHeight;
          // Set intial mode to login
          AuthMode _authMode = AuthMode.LOGIN;
          @override

          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
            return Scaffold(
              body: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Stack(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    lowerHalf(context),
                    upperHalf(context),
                    _authMode == AuthMode.LOGIN
                        ? loginCard(context)
                        : singUpCard(context),
                    pageTitle(),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            );
          }


          Widget loginCard(BuildContext context) {
            return Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: screenHeight / 4),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10),
                  child: Card(
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    ),
                    elevation: 8,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Align(
                            alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                            child: Text(
                              "Login",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.black,
                                fontSize: 28,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 15,
                          ),
                          TextFormField(
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                                labelText: "Your Email", hasFloatingPlaceholder: true),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 20,
                          ),
                          TextFormField(
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                                labelText: "Password", hasFloatingPlaceholder: true),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 20,
                          ),
                          Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              MaterialButton(
                                onPressed: () {},
                                child: Text("Forgot Password ?"),
                              ),
                              Expanded(
                                child: Container(),
                              ),
                              FlatButton(
                                child: Text("Login"),
                                color: Color(0xFF4B9DFE),
                                textColor: Colors.white,
                                padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                    left: 38, right: 38, top: 15, bottom: 15),
                                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
                                onPressed: () {},
                              )
                            ],
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Row(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 40,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      "Don't have an account ?",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                    ),
                    FlatButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          _authMode = AuthMode.SINGUP;
                        });
                      },
                      textColor: Colors.black87,
                      child: Text("Create Account"),
                    )
                  ],
                )
              ],
            );
          }

          Widget upperHalf(BuildContext context) {
            return Container(
              height: screenHeight / 2,
              child: Image.asset(
                'assets/house.jpg',
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            );
          }

          Widget lowerHalf(BuildContext context) {
            return Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              child: Container(
                height: screenHeight / 2,
                color: Color(0xFFECF0F3),
              ),
            );
          }
        }
```

This is the plugin I found so far:
**carousel_slider: ^1.3.1**. But I think the purpose is different.

I know how to display an image but I couldn't manage to use the plugin above instead of the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Stack your Login Form with carousel_slider 
and Positioned your Login Form with Positioned widget 
You can see demo picture for effect 
full code

```
import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final List<String> imgList = [
  'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1520342868574-5fa3804e551c?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=6ff92caffcdd63681a35134a6770ed3b&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1951&q=80',
  'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1522205408450-add114ad53fe?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=368f45b0888aeb0b7b08e3a1084d3ede&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80',
  'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1519125323398-675f0ddb6308?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=94a1e718d89ca60a6337a6008341ca50&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80',
  'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1523205771623-e0faa4d2813d?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=89719a0d55dd05e2deae4120227e6efc&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1953&q=80',
  'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1508704019882-f9cf40e475b4?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=8c6e5e3aba713b17aa1fe71ab4f0ae5b&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1352&q=80',
  'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1519985176271-adb1088fa94c?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=a0c8d632e977f94e5d312d9893258f59&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1355&q=80'
];

void main() => runApp(CarouselDemo());

final Widget placeholder = Container(color: Colors.grey);

final List child = map<Widget>(
  imgList,
      (index, i) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
      child: ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0)),
        child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
          Image.network(i, fit: BoxFit.cover, width: 1000.0),
          Positioned(
            bottom: 0.0,
            left: 0.0,
            right: 0.0,
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                gradient: LinearGradient(
                  colors: [Color.fromARGB(200, 0, 0, 0), Color.fromARGB(0, 0, 0, 0)],
                  begin: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                  end: Alignment.topCenter,
                ),
              ),
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 20.0),
              child: Text(
                'No. $index image',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 20.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ]),
      ),
    );
  },
).toList();

List<T> map<T>(List list, Function handler) {
  List<T> result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    result.add(handler(i, list[i]));
  }

  return result;
}

class CarouselWithIndicator extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CarouselWithIndicatorState createState() => _CarouselWithIndicatorState();
}

class _CarouselWithIndicatorState extends State<CarouselWithIndicator> {
  int _current = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(children: [
      CarouselSlider(
        items: child,
        autoPlay: true,
        enlargeCenterPage: true,
        aspectRatio: 2.0,
        onPageChanged: (index) {
          setState(() {
            _current = index;
          });
        },
      ),
      Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: map<Widget>(
          imgList,
              (index, url) {
            return Container(
              width: 8.0,
              height: 8.0,
              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 2.0),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                  color: _current == index
                      ? Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.9)
                      : Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.4)),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    ]);
  }
}

class CarouselDemo extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //Manually operated Carousel
    final CarouselSlider manualCarouselDemo = CarouselSlider(
      items: child,
      autoPlay: false,
      enlargeCenterPage: true,
      viewportFraction: 0.9,
      aspectRatio: 2.0,
    );

    //Auto playing carousel
    final CarouselSlider autoPlayDemo = CarouselSlider(
      viewportFraction: 0.9,
      aspectRatio: 2.0,
      autoPlay: true,
      enlargeCenterPage: true,
      items: imgList.map(
            (url) {
          return Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
            child: ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0)),
              child: Image.network(
                url,
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                width: 1000.0,
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ).toList(),
    );

    //Button controlled carousel
    Widget buttonDemo() {
      final basicSlider = CarouselSlider(
        items: child,
        autoPlay: false,
        enlargeCenterPage: true,
        viewportFraction: 0.9,
        aspectRatio: 2.0,
      );
      return Column(children: [
        basicSlider,
        Row(children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15.0),
              child: RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () => basicSlider.previousPage(
                    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300), curve: Curves.linear),
                child: Text('prev slider'),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15.0),
              child: RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () => basicSlider.nextPage(
                    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300), curve: Curves.linear),
                child: Text('next slider'),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ]),
      ]);
    }

    //Pages covers entire carousel
    final CarouselSlider coverScreenExample = CarouselSlider(
      viewportFraction: 1.0,
      aspectRatio: 2.0,
      autoPlay: false,
      enlargeCenterPage: false,
      items: map<Widget>(
        imgList,
            (index, i) {
          return Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(image: NetworkImage(i), fit: BoxFit.cover),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );

    //User input pauses carousels automatic playback
    final CarouselSlider touchDetectionDemo = CarouselSlider(
      viewportFraction: 0.9,
      aspectRatio: 2.0,
      autoPlay: true,
      enlargeCenterPage: true,
      pauseAutoPlayOnTouch: Duration(seconds: 3),
      items: imgList.map(
            (url) {
          return Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
            child: ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0)),
              child: Image.network(
                url,
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                width: 1000.0,
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ).toList(),
    );

    //Non-looping manual Carousel
    final CarouselSlider nonLoopingCarousel = CarouselSlider(
      items: child,
      //scrollPhysics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
      enableInfiniteScroll: false,
      autoPlay: false,
      enlargeCenterPage: true,
      viewportFraction: 0.9,
      aspectRatio: 2.0,
    );

    //Vertical carousel
    final CarouselSlider verticalScrollCarousel = CarouselSlider(
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      aspectRatio: 2.0,
      autoPlay: true,
      enlargeCenterPage: true,
      viewportFraction: 0.9,
      pauseAutoPlayOnTouch: Duration(seconds: 3),
      items: imgList.map(
            (url) {
          return Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
            child: ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0)),
              child: Image.network(
                url,
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                width: 1000.0,
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ).toList(),
    );

    //create full screen Carousel with context
    CarouselSlider getFullScreenCarousel(BuildContext mediaContext) {
      return CarouselSlider(
        autoPlay: true,
        viewportFraction: 1.0,
        aspectRatio: MediaQuery.of(mediaContext).size.aspectRatio,
        items: imgList.map(
              (url) {
            return Container(
              child: ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(0.0)),
                child: Image.network(
                  url,
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  width: 1000.0,
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        ).toList(),
      );
    }

    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'demo',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Carousel slider demo')),
        body: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15.0),
                child: Column(children: [
                  Text('Manuell Carousel'),
                  manualCarouselDemo,
                ])),
            Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15.0),
                child: Column(children: [
                  Text('Auto Playing Carousel'),
                  autoPlayDemo,
                ])),
            Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15.0),
                child: Column(children: [
                  Text('Button Controlled Carousel'),
                  buttonDemo(),
                ])),
            Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15.0),
                child: Column(children: [
                  Text('Full Screen Carousel'),
                  coverScreenExample,
                ])),
            Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15.0),
                child: Column(children: [
                  Text('Carousel With Indecator'),
                  CarouselWithIndicator(),
                ])),
            Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15.0),
                child: Column(children: [
                  Text('Pause When Touched Carousel'),
                  touchDetectionDemo,
                ])),
            Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15.0),
                child: Column(children: [
                  Text('No infinity scroll carousel'),
                  nonLoopingCarousel,
                ])),
            Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15.0),
                child: Column(children: [
                  Text('Vertical scroll carousel'),
                  verticalScrollCarousel,
                ])),
            Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0),
                //Builder needed to provide mediaQuery context from material app
                child: Builder(builder: (context) {
                  return Column(children: [
                    Text('Full screen carousel'),
                    getFullScreenCarousel(context),
                  ]);
                })),
          ],
        ),Positioned(
                bottom: 48.0,
                left: 10.0,
                right: 10.0,
                child: Card(
                  elevation: 8.0,
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                  ),
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                        child: Text(
                          "Your Login Form",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 20.0,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                        child: Text(
                            "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book."),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),],
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: ok, I'm try to implementation your code.. thank you so much sir.